# ESXi VM ServerID changes after installing sonar8.5 Development Edition

Tags: sonarqube

Can someone help me understand that why ServerID changes when I install SONAR 8.3 Dev Edition on the ESXi VM where I have SONAR Opensource 7.6.

I am installing new Dev Edition under /opt/sonar8.5 where as my opensource 7.6 is installed under /opt/sonar7.6
The problem is that I am seeing license key error because now it complaining about serverID
mismatch.
I already sent email to my sonar license support person in SONAR to help me.BUt trying to understand if someone also faced something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Similar case has happened with us as well. The ServerID is relevant to licensing is based on the **Database Connection String**, not on the host url. So, whenever you change the **Database Connection String**, serverID will be re-generated and you will need license for that serverID.

You can find the more explanation here:

1. https://community.sonarsource.com/t/will-the-server-id-change-if-i-move-sonarqube-to-a-new-host-instance/3820
2. https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/license-manager/